# Displaying Posts Using a Custom Query with a Custom Field and a term_id

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, loop

I'd like to display a list of posts in a category of a taxonomy using a Custom Field.
Here's my code:

```
if($current_term->term_id=='143') {     
   $querystr = "  SELECT wposts.*
        FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->terms wpterms
        WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
        AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'apecard'
        AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'on'     
        AND wpterms.term_id  =  '143'
        AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND wposts.post_type = 'locali'
        ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC ";
 .....
```

The results display all posts that have meta_key='apecard' in every category of the taxonomy. But I want to display that posts only in the category with term_id=143.
Thanks you!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'locali',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'apecard',
            'value' => 'on',
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'yourtaxonomy',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array('143')
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Nego90 you can accept answer.....